# Multi-part identifier error in WHERE code SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query written to find time gaps in my data. I'm getting "the multi-part identifier can not be bound" errors for code in my where statement (i.e. for xref.Begin_date and animals.Species). Any idea why that is? I thought I specified it in my Inner join select code.

```
SELECT *,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, prev_DateYearAndJulian, DateYearAndJulian) AS diff_hours
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         points.OBJECTID, points.CollarSerialNum, points.Latitude, 
         points.Longitude, points.DateYearAndJulian,
         LAG(DateYearAndJulian) OVER (PARTITION BY points.CollarSerialNum ORDER BY points.DateYearAndJulian) AS prev_DateYearAndJulian
     FROM 
         ANIMALS AS animals 
     INNER JOIN 
         ANIMAL_COLLAR_XREF AS xref ON xref.UniqueID = animals.UniqueID 
                                    AND xref.CollarSerialNum = animals.CollarID 
                                    AND xref.Begin_Date = animals.Begin_Date 
     INNER JOIN 
         COLLARS AS points ON points.CollarSerialNum = animals.CollarID) d
WHERE
    (DateYearAndJulian BETWEEN xref.Begin_Date AND COALESCE (xref.End_Date, GETDATE() + 1))
    AND DATEDIFF(HOUR, prev_DateYearAndJulian, DateYearAndJulian) > 13
    AND animals.Species = 'mule deer'
```

This is my desired output from the collars table with the headers CollarSerialNum, DateYearAndJulian and diff_hours:

```
040142  2018-01-07 22:00:00.0000000 040142  2018-01-16 00:00:00.0000000 194
040142  2019-12-09 16:00:00.0000000 040142  2019-12-10 18:00:00.0000000 26
040142  2020-01-10 22:00:00.0000000 040142  2020-01-12 04:50:00.0000000 30
040142  2018-08-18 23:00:00.0000000 040142  2018-08-21 03:00:00.0000000 52
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xref` is inside a subquery and is not visible in the outer query, which has access only to the columns of `d`.  Either project the `Begin_Date` and `End_Date` columns out of the subquery, or push the `WHERE` clause into the subquery.

Comment: Oh! That makes a lot of sense. I moved part of the where clause into the subquery and that worked. Thank you!